# HTML, Create line numbers for large lines

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that create automatic line numbers, for each div with the class "lineNum". I want to create line numbers also to the break lines (in the code snippet, the lines between line number 1 and 2).
Thanks!

```css
.container {direction:rtl; counter-reset: line;}
.container .lineNum {display: flex;line-height: 1.5rem;}
.lineNum>center, .lineNum>right, .lineNum>left, .lineNum>span 
{width: 100%;}

.container .lineNum:before 
{
  width: 2%;font-weight: bold;
  counter-increment: line;content:counter(line);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="lineNum"><span>במהלך תקופה זו, גדלנו מקבוצה קטנה של עורכים לקהילה מגוונת של עורכים, מפתחים, קוראים, תורמים ושותפים. איפה נהיה בעוד 15 שנה? איזה תפקיד נמלא בעולם? מי עוד יצטרף לתנועה? מה אופי העבודה הניצבת לפנינו? שאלות אלו ייענו על ידי תנועת ויקימדיה כולה במהלך השבועות הקרובים, במסגרת התהליך האסטרטגי לשנת 2017, המתנהל בימים אלו.</span></div>
<div class="lineNum"><span>תצלום לוויין של ארץ ישראל, משנת 2003, הכולל את מדינת ישראל, שטחי הרשות הפלסטינית, וחלקים מירדן, לבנון, סוריה ומצרים</span></div></div>
```

edit:
the follow result is expected
[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you want a break inbetween each `.lineNum` class, simply add a `margin-top: 10px;` I have added a snippet below to show you.

```css
.container {direction:rtl; counter-reset: line;}
.container .lineNum {display: flex;line-height: 1.5rem;}
.lineNum>center, .lineNum>right, .lineNum>left, .lineNum>span 
{width: 100%;}

.lineNum {margin-top: 10px;} 
       
.container .lineNum:before 
{
  width: 2%;font-weight: bold;
  counter-increment: line;content:counter(line);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="lineNum"><span>במהלך תקופה זו, גדלנו מקבוצה קטנה של עורכים לקהילה מגוונת של עורכים, מפתחים, קוראים, תורמים ושותפים. איפה נהיה בעוד 15 שנה? איזה תפקיד נמלא בעולם? מי עוד יצטרף לתנועה? מה אופי העבודה הניצבת לפנינו? שאלות אלו ייענו על ידי תנועת ויקימדיה כולה במהלך השבועות הקרובים, במסגרת התהליך האסטרטגי לשנת 2017, המתנהל בימים אלו.</span></div>
<div class="lineNum"><span>תצלום לוויין של ארץ ישראל, משנת 2003, הכולל את מדינת ישראל, שטחי הרשות הפלסטינית, וחלקים מירדן, לבנון, סוריה ומצרים</span></div></div>
```

Comment: sorry for misunderstand me, I upload image of the expected result, thanks

Comment: @yossico He changed his question further, that's why.